# Soap php wsdl, как составить запросы?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Привет. Не знаю правильно ли я вообще задаю вопрос, так как на тостере не помогли особо. Решил задать здесь.

Мне нужно интегрировать на мой сайт калькулятор и систему отслеживания с сайта [ксэ](https://lk.cse.ru/help/integration)

Посмотрел их api и впервые даже узнал о существовании метода "soap". Потом погуглил и, как выяснилось, soap нужно использовать в php (в котором я тоже не силен).

Я не прошу делать это Вас, я прошу только кинуть мне маленький кусок кода, от которого я смогу отталкиваться и общаться с сервером в дальнейшем сам. То есть как через php передать данные используя soap с сервера по [wdsl](http://web.cse.ru/1c/ws/Web1C.1cws?wsdl) на мой сайт?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator. Передав ему ссылку на WSDL он сгенерирует все необходимое для вызова. Там есть примеры для большинства случаев.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо за наводку. Буду пробовать.